# ∀: ((∀ ∶ ( = ) ∨ ( ⊈ )) → ( = ∅))

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, predicate-logic

**∀: ((∀ ∶ ( = ) ∨ ( ⊈ )) → ( = ∅))** where A and B are sets.

The main problem was to either prove or disprove the statement.

I do not know how to approach the proof.

If I fix A, then if `∀ B ((B=A) ∨ (B ⊈ A))` is false, any implication from it always true so we can ignore the cases when it is false. Because P→Q is always true when P is false.

Now, about the case when for a fix A , `∀ B ((B=A) ∨ (B ⊈ A))` is true. What should it imply? Because when P is true and Q is false P→Q is false.

I am stuck here and I don't even know if this is the way to solve. Please show a proper approach.

Thank you.

Comment: Set $B = \emptyset$.

Comment: An implication is false, *only* when the consequent is false and the antecedent is true. The point is, can you find a particular set $A$, such that $\forall B , (B = A) \vee (B \nsubseteq A)$ is true, but $A = \emptyset$ is false? Think about it in words : the first statement says that for every set $B$, either $B$ equals $A$ or $B$ is *not* a strict subset of $A$, and the second says that $A$ is non-empty. Can any $A$ satisfy these properties? Use the $B$ given in Brian's hint for help, and let me know if you didn't understand anything I said.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon so taking B=∅, and assuming (B=A)∨(B⊈A)  is true, that is, either B=A which give A=∅ or B⊈A which also gives A=∅ since the empty set is a proper subset of every set except for the empty set.  This shows that the statement is true in this case, i.e., B is empty implies that A is also empty. We can prove the statement is false by providing a single contradictory case, but since the statement is true here how do we generalize it ∀A∀B.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon If A is empty then the implication is always true regardless of the left hand side of the statement. If A is not empty, only when left hand side of the statement is false the implication would be true. Assume A={1} and B={1} as well, since A=B the left hand side of the implication is true, so for the statement to be true, A should be a null set but it is not so right?

Comment: I'm sorry for being wrong above, I should have double checked. You're right : If $A$ is empty, then the implication is true regardless. However, the left side of the implication is "$\forall B, A = B \vee B \nsubseteq A$" , so proving that for one particular $B$ we have $A =B \vee B \nsubseteq A$ is true, is not equal to proving that the entire "$\forall B, A = B \vee B \nsubseteq A$" is true. In fact, you can see that if $\{A\} = 1$ and $ B = \emptyset$ then $A \neq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, so the LHS of the implication is actually false. It will be false if $A$ is non-empty, in fact.

Comment: Which is why the statement given, is actually true : If $A$ is empty, then the RHS of the implication is true. If $A$ is not empty, then taking $B = \emptyset$ we can see that the LHS of the implication is actually always false. So in either case, the implication itself is a true statement for all $A$, so the whole statement is true.

Comment: @ksgr5566 the antecedent is only true if it holds for *all* $B$ ; one is not enough.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes I get that when B=∅ and A is non empty the LHS is false. Okay that's fine but we gotta generalize it for ∀B right.

Comment: @ksgr5566 Once the statement is false for one $B$, the "for all $B$" version of the statement is false,right? To give an example : let's say you have a box, and you make a statement : every ball in this box is white. I remove a ball from it and it is yellow, so obviously one ball being yellow makes the statement "for every ball in the box, the colour of the ball is white" false, right? Something like that is happening with the LHS and $B$ : For $B = \emptyset$ it is false, so therefore, it can't be true for every possible $B$ because we already found a $B$ for which it's false.

Comment: Just a reminder : the LHS is "for all $B$, we have either $A = B$ or $B =\nsubseteq A$". The $\forall B$ part is part of the LHS, so when we say the LHS is false, we're including the forall $B$ in that.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks a lot. Done with this now.

Comment: @ksgr5566 Sorry for the late response, but good to have been of some help!

Comment: Oh, and +1 for participating in a nice conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few points to make here.

First, if you're trying to prove an implication $P \to Q$, there's no need to do case analysis on whether $P$ is true or false. This just unnecessarily lengthens the proof. Instead, simply assume $P$ and prove $Q$.

So in this case, we assume that $\forall B . (B = A \lor B \nsubseteq A)$. We seek to prove $A = \emptyset$.

As suggested in the comments, the correct thing to do here is to set $B = \emptyset$ (or, more formally, apply the universal elimination rule on $B = \emptyset$). Then we see that either $\emptyset = A$ or $\emptyset \nsubseteq A$. I'll let you finish the proof from here.

If we had significant difficulty proving $A = \emptyset$ from the hypothesis $\forall B . (B = a \lor B \nsubseteq A)$, we would have tried to come up with a counterexample.